# String Array (String[ ][ ]) output in JSP

Tags: java, arrays, string, jsp, printing

I'm totally new to JSP. What I want is to basically print a String[][] with JSP like I did on console in eclipse before:

```
public void printField(String[][] field){
        for (int i = 0; i < field.length-1; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < field[i].length-1; j++){
                String x = field[j][i];
                System.out.print("|");

                if (x.equals(" ")){
                    System.out.print("   ");
                } else if (x.equals("S")) {
                    System.out.print(" S ");
                } else if (x.equals("x")) {
                    System.out.print(" x ");
                } else if (x.equals("#")){
                    System.out.print(" # ");
                } else if (x.equals("*")){
                    System.out.print(" * ");
                }
                else if (x.equals("10")){
                    System.out.print(" "+x );
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(" " +x +" ");
                }
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }
        System.out.println();
}
```

it would like this:

```
| 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10|
| 1 | S |   |   | S | S | S |   | S |   |   |
| 2 | S |   |   |   |   |   |   | S |   |   |
| 3 |   | S |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 4 |   | S |   | S |   |   |   |   |   |   |
| 5 | S |   |   | S |   |   | S |   | S |   |
| 6 | S |   |   | S |   |   | S |   | S |   |
| 7 | S |   |   | S |   |   | S |   | S |   |
| 8 | S |   |   |   |   |   | S |   |   | S |
| 9 |   |   |   |   |   |   | S |   |   | S |
| 10|   |   |   | S | S | S |   |   |   |   |
```

Just as general information: I have coded battleship. What I do want to do is to create a web based front end now, that's why I'm asking. I will replace this field output with graphical items later. But it's just for learning purposes.

Comment: you can use html tags like `p`, `br` to make html content instead of sout

Comment: you must learn how stackoverflow works... a) you cannot answer yourself to make an update, you must edit the original question, b) what you are asking now is a totally different question, original was about jsp and pass data to request, now you have problem with constructing html and c) as told in comments, what I gave you was a guide and as you can see in the result, **UNTESTED APPROACH WRITTEN ON THE FLY** now you must work to get desired design or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all. Did you realized all this conditions are totally unnecessary???

```
if (x.equals(" ")){
    System.out.print("   ");
} else if (x.equals("S")) {
    System.out.print(" S ");
} else if (x.equals("x")) {
    System.out.print(" x ");
} // others....
```

you take the value and add a space first and after... then your code is same as:

```
if (x.equals("10")){
    System.out.print(" "+x );
} else {
    System.out.print(" " + x + " ");
}
```

Also you can use `String.format`... but anyway...

---

To display this structure in a JSP:

Set your attribute in the request

```
request.setAttribute("field", field);
```

Then in the JSP:

```
<table class="your_class">
    <thead>
        not necessary
    </thead>
```

then iterate over elements with :

```
    <tbody>
        <!-- each item in field will be an 1d array -->
        <c:forEach items="${field}" var="row">
            <td> |
                <tr class="your_class">
                <!-- each item in row will be an element -->
                <c:forEach items="${row}" var="item">
                    ${item} |
                </c:forEach>
                </tr>
            </td>
        </c:forEach>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not necessarily sure that JSP code will work. Every time you output `${item}` your creating a new row with it. I've done something like this before and its a little trickier.  The row creation needs to lay between the loops.

Comment: @RaymondHolguin agree, just marked the path for the op, but is an untested code written *on the fly*

Comment: No worries, I understood that.  its just that since the OP is new to JSP he might think its a working example because it isn't noted in your answer that is just a rough starting point.

Comment: Ok, corrected, hope is right now... Still on the fly xD